# NSView over WKWebView user interaction

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, wkwebview

I am making an app for MacOSX. I have a menu with NSView laying over WKWebView:

[image]

My problem is when I move mouse over NSView menu or click on some controls within this NSView I also get interaction with WKWebView at the same time.
I get hover for HTML elements inside webview and webview elements gets clicked when I click on NSView menu.
My question is how to prevent WKWebView from any interactions and make only NSView to interact when I click or move mouse over NSView?

Comment: I have seen this and assumed it was a bug in Mac OS.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a bug, I believe that only the top view must interact. I am just trying to find some workaround. May be disabling the WebView when menu is visible, but I can't find such option for WKWebView to disable any interactions.

Comment: The macOS web view has no way of disabling user interactions, AFAIK. I've approached a similar problem in a pretty hacky way, and set a class containing `pointer-events: none;` through JavaScript into `body`. This is mostly only applicable in case you have control over what is displayed in the web view and when.

Comment: Thank you, Tritonal! I've ended up making the menu just left and right side from the WebView, not over it. It limits me a bit, but app still looks fine. Not so good work, Apple! :)